# Combining behaviours: buttons (checkboxes) and collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8072/

Can anybody suggest why the above fiddle doesn't work?

I'm trying to use the bootstrap `button` and `collapse` behaviours together. It works fine if you remove `data-toggle="buttons"`but that messes with the styling.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the wrong element the `data-toggle` and `data-target`. You have to give it to the `label`, not the `input`.

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#person">
                <input type="checkbox" id="person-btn" /><span class="hidden-xs">Person</span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#vehicle">
                <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle-btn" /><span class="hidden-xs">Vehicle</span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8073/)